# Unable to create NetGraph

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to perform deep learning classification in Mathematica. I noted that I am unable to create `NetGraph` even when I just follow the simple steps in the help document of `NetGraph`.

I also tried to run those codes in Wolfram Programming Lab at the Cloud as well, and the codes can be run without occurring any error. How can I get rid of those errors in Mathematica as well?

Input 1:

```
net = NetGraph[{ElementwiseLayer[Ramp]}, {}]
```

Input 1 - Result:

```
$Failed
NetGraph: ElementwiseLayer[Ramp] is not a net function.
```

Input 2:

```
net = NetGraph[{LinearLayer[3], LinearLayer[5]}, {1 -> 2}, "Input" -> 2]
```

Input 2 - Result:

```
$Failed
NetGraph::netinvnodes: LinearLayer[3] is not a net function.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just upgrade to v11.3 on the desktop and don't use the cloud - it never works for anything other than toy examples.

[image]